# Differences between ways to pass function as parameter in Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the difference between these two lines of code (except the fact that second line has an inline function calling "setThing").
I noticed that on the first case Angular change detection didn't run.

```
someObservable<Thing>.subscribe<Thing>(this.setThing) // change detection didn't run
someObservable<Thing>.subscribe<Thing>(thing => this.setThing(thing)); // change detection worked

setThing(thing :Thing) {
    this.thing = thing;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `this` inside the function. In the first one you lose the lexical `this`, in the second you don't.

Example:

First one:

```
setThing(thing :Thing) {
    this.myTemplateThing = thing; // Since your this is not refering to the component you won't be seeing a change
}
```